# Get the remaining time value using jQuery.countdownTimer.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have set up a countdown timer using `jQuery.countdownTimer.js`

the timer is  defined

```
<div id='countdowntimer'><span id='cdt'></span></div>
```

and the corresponding javascript is

```
  $(function(){
    $('#cdt').countdowntimer({
    seconds : 60,
    size : 'md',
    pauseButton : null,                            
    stopButton : null,
    timeUp : myfin,
    borderColor              : '#FFFFFF',
    fontColor                : '#000000',
    backgroundColor          : '#FFFFFF',
    });
  });
```

It works fine and on 0 it calls `myfin()`. I would like to get the remaining time value to use it on a function.

I tried using `document.getElementById("cdt").value` but get only `undefinded`.

Comment: A `span` has no value. Try with `document.getElementById("cdt").innerHTML` (plain JS) or with `$("#cdt").html()` (jQuery).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could get the value **$("#cdt").html()** or **$("#cdt").html().match(/\d+/g)**

```
        $(function() {
            $('#cdt').countdowntimer({
                seconds : 60,
                size : 'md',
                pauseButton : null,
                stopButton : null,
                timeUp : myfin,
                borderColor : '#FFFFFF',
                fontColor : '#000000',
                backgroundColor : '#FFFFFF'
            });
        });

        function myfin() {
            console.log("Option Value 1 (full value):  " +  $("#cdt").html());
            console.log("Option Value 2 (Numbers Only):  " +  $("#cdt").html().match(/\d+/g));
        }
```